# Is it possible to binding "properties" ranther than "property" in Binding?

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qtquick2, qt-quick

I'm writing Binding for Loader's item. Let's start from my case after simplifying. Assuming that CustomItem is an customized item that has properties named prop1,prop2, and I use it as Loader's source component. When I want to initialize prop1 and prop2 in Loader, I have to do like

```
Loader {
    id: loader
    sourceComponent: comp
    Binding {
        target: loader.item
        property: "prop1"
        when: loader.status === Loader.Ready
        value: control.prop1
    }
    Binding {
        target: loader.item
        property: "prop2"
        when: loader.status === Loader.Ready
        value: control.prop2
    }
}
```

Is it possible to bind more value in one Binding? Note that you cannot

```
Binding {
    loader.item.prop1: control.prop1
    loader.item.prop2: control.prop2
}
```

Additionally, cna I initilize `required` property of source component?

Comment: I cannot see why you want to do this. If you want to pass parameters into your loaded component, instead of setting the source property, you can consider using Loader.setSource() which allows you to feed in parameters. If they must be bound, I suppose you can wrap them with Qt.binding.

Comment: @StephenQuan But I'm using `sourceComponent`, and `setSource` requires an url as parameter.

Comment: Then move the source code to a file, refer to the file via setSource() and pass parameters.

Comment: Why is this tagged with C++? I find no relevance or reference to C++ anywhere inside the question.

Comment: @Red.Wave QML can be extended with C++, what OP is asking could be done in with a helper wrote in C++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me share the awesome solution from @GrecKo answered [here](https://forum.qt.io/topic/147805/is-it-possible-to-binding-properties-ranther-than-property-in-binding/2)

```
Instantiator {
    model: ["prop1", "prop2"]
    delegate: Binding {
        target: loader.item
        property: modelData
        value: control[modelData]
   } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is a demonstration to create multiple property bindings using Loader.setSource() and Qt.binding():

```js
loader.setSource("Comp1.qml", {
    prop1: Qt.binding( () => slider1.value),
    prop2: Qt.binding( () => slider2.value)
} );
```

Here's a full working code snippet:

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
import QtQuick.Layouts
Page {
    ColumnLayout {
        Slider {
           id: slider1
           from: 0; to: 100; value: 20
        }
        Slider {
           id: slider2
           from: 0; to: 100; value: 40
        }
        Loader {
            id: loader
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            Layout.fillHeight: true
        }
        RowLayout {
            Button {
                text: "Comp1"
                onClicked: {
loader.setSource("Comp1.qml", {
    prop1: Qt.binding( () => slider1.value),
    prop2: Qt.binding( () => slider2.value)
} );
                }
            }
            Button {
                text: "Comp2"
                onClicked: {
loader.setSource("Comp2.qml", {
    prop1: Qt.binding( () => slider1.value),
    prop2: Qt.binding( () => slider2.value)
} );
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

// Comp1.qml
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
import QtQuick.Layouts
ColumnLayout {
    Label { text: "Comp1.qml" }
    property var prop1
    property var prop2
    Frame { Label { text: prop1 } }
    Frame { Label { text: prop2 } }
}

// Comp2.qml
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
import QtQuick.Layouts
ColumnLayout {
    Label { text: "Comp2.qml" }
    property var prop1
    property var prop2
    TextField { text: prop1 }
    TextField { text: prop2 }
}
```

You can [Try it Online!](https://stephenquan.github.io/qmlonline/?zcode=AAAFXniczVOxbsIwEN39FScmkFAgVqegdmgk1IGhlEqdAzFg1cmljt0Wofx7HTsFkpCKMlS9yX73/HLvLseTDKWCuZprvnolvHb1QkyVRJE38Vm0Q61y8hhtGOwJmAhR6CR1iQoqYyF4zOQJYILHAeQW90/htcQkgPEEFAbgj83hPRKaBUDHB1pxoTC9SPjmnPAMo5awVRY2UYOdXW/NhXjhsdoGoKRmXZQHxjdb1eAcP/yEH632lXGvlcK0AZah2KdR64WYZH6vlcU0FGZWzFS+J652L2dqgVquWN+98t4S0RtW0pnEzA/MjL0lT2OebvrQH8Dt3fesPNu1wfBApt1kWpFJAYNJq7SCdN8ucUuvckv/mVt3KkhByGgEh3k0du23K3lmD2fRkgnY1/4X24uqhNIdk2pn1kK6vpyH3VJNZZSYpW+o2mdQVIrdHGo5R8v0zyzT6y0/G5UpZyJu2v0hS0ubXzL0gvI=)

Comment: However, I'm writting a reusable component, the `comp` in my code is `delegate` property that can be specified by user, so I cannot write `comp` as a file.

Answer (score 0):

Your example doesn't show where `comp` comes from. You can add bindings at the time that you create the component too, and therefore still use sourceComponent in the Loader.

```
Component {
    id: comp
    SomeObject {
        prop1: control.prop1
        prop2: control.prop2
    }
}

Loader {
    sourceComponent: comp
}
```